# Cannot run go install on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, golang

When I run the `go install` command for my custom packages on Ubuntu 14.04 I got this error:

```
go install: no install location for .go files listed on command line (GOBIN not set)
```

How can i set `$GOBIN` relative in my projects directory in `[anyproject]/bin`?

Answer (score 1):

In go, there is a directory with all binaries rather than one *bin* directory per project.

So let's say you want all your go binaries to be in `$HOME/go/bin`. Then run

```
mkdir $HOME/go/bin
GOBIN=$HOME/go/bin; export GOBIN
```

However you don't need to set GOBIN if the GOROOT environment variable is set up properly. So I suggest using the instructions given in https://golang.org/doc/install

Also see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/-mN8R_Fx-7M where Russ Cox informs:

> If GOBIN is set, that's where binaries end up.  If GOBIN is not set, then the binaries end up in a directory named 'bin' under the root of the tree where the source code lives.  For things in $GOROOT, that means
> `$GOROOT/bin`.  For things in in a GOPATH directory DIR, that means DIR/bin.  Note that GOPATH can have multiple directories in it
>
> ```
> export GOPATH=/dir1:/dir2:/dir3
> ```
>
> If GOBIN is not set, binaries from `/dir1/src` end up in `/dir1/bin`, binaries from `/dir2/src` end up in `/dir2/bin`, and so on (and binaries from `$GOROOT/src` end up in `$GOROOT/bin`).